# ¿Cómo mejorar la gráfica de la curva de ROC en R?

Tags: r, glm, plot

Tengo un modelo logit binomial y estoy evaluando la bondad del ajuste de mi modelo mediante la **curva de ROC**:

```
library(pROC)
curva_ROC <- roc(modelo_logit_viv$y,modelo_logit_viv$fitted.values)
plot(curva_ROC,col = "blue",xlim = c(1,0),ylim = c(0,1),
     xlab = "Especifidad", ylab ="Sensibilidad", main = "Curva de ROC")
auc(curva_ROC) # 0.8445
```

Esta es la gráfica que me devuelve:

[image: Curva de ROC]

Quiero modificarla de la siguiente manera:

- Acotar el eje x (especifidad) de tal manera que el inicio esté casi en 1 y acabe en 0, es decir, que **los límites del eje horizontal coincidan con la diagonal** (pensé que al indicar `xlab = c(0,1)` obtendría ese resultado, pero la gráfica no varía al incluir este argumento en la función plot).
- Que el **área comprendida entre la curva y la diagonal esté coloreada** en un azul más claro que la curva.
- **Que aparezca el valor del área** `auc(curva_ROC)` justo en el centro de dicha área.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### 1. Ajustar ejes

La forma de hacerlo en las gráficas base es mediante los parámetros `xlim` e `ylim` no pude verificarlo con tus datos, pero funciona adecuadamente con el ejemplo que armé para esta respuesta. Por otro lado `xlab` e `ylab` solo establecen los "labels" o etiquetas de cada eje

#### 2. Colorear área

El comportamiento de [`plot.ROC()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/pROC/versions/1.16.2/topics/plot.roc) admite colorear el área completa de la curva, mediante estos parámetros (ejemplo):

```
auc.polygon = TRUE 
auc.polygon.col=rgb(.35,0.31,0.61, alpha = 0.4)
```

Sin embargo, lo que buscas, es colorear la curva hasta la diagonal. Una forma podría ser, generar el polígono por debajo de la curva y hasta la diagonal, aprovechando los datos del propio `plot.ROC()`

```
polygon(with(p, cbind(specificities, sensitivities)), 
        col = rgb(.25,0.31,0.61, alpha = 0.4), 
        border = "blue",
        lwd = 2)
```

#### 3. Texto con el valor AUC

Lo puedes configurar y ajustar con los siguientes parámetros:

```
print.auc = TRUE,
print.auc.x = 0.73,
print.auc.y = 0.6
```

Los valores de `x` e  `y` los deberías ajustar para que el texto entre dentro del área.

#### Ejemplo

```
library(pROC)

curva_ROC = roc(aSAH$outcome, aSAH$s100b, levels=c("Good", "Poor"))
p <- plot(curva_ROC,
          col = "blue",
          print.auc = TRUE,
          print.auc.x = 0.73,
          print.auc.y = 0.6, 
          xlim = c(1,0),
          ylim = c(0,1),
          xlab = "Especifidad", 
          ylab ="Sensibilidad", 
          main = "Curva de ROC")

polygon(with(p, cbind(specificities, sensitivities)), 
        col = rgb(.25,0.31,0.61, alpha = 0.4), 
        border = "blue",
        lwd = 2)
```

#### Resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

#### Fuentes:

- [How to fill in AUC of a ROC plot in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35539581/how-to-fill-in-auc-of-a-roc-plot-in-r)
- [Polygon in R “stopping” at the diagonal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35544160/polygon-in-r-stopping-at-the-diagonal?rq=1)

Comment: Funciona a la perfección ¿Cómo podría hacer para que solo aparezca el área de la curva sin el  "AUC: "?

Comment: Puedes agregar `print.auc.pattern = "%f"`

Comment: ¿Por qué las curvas ROC presentan el eje y "invertido" (del 1 al 0 y no al revés)?